# Java script object mapping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a c# method which convert from source to destination object like this

```
public static object ToMapping(this object source, object destination)
        {
            //loop through the properties of the object you want to covert:          
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in source.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                try
                {
                    //get the value of property and try 
                    //to assign it to the property of destination object:
                    if (pi != null && pi.CanRead && pi.CanWrite)
                    {
                        var val = pi.GetValue(source, null);
                        if (val == null)
                            if (pi.PropertyType != typeof(Nullable))
                                continue;
                        destination.GetType().GetProperty(pi.Name).SetValue(destination, pi.GetValue(source, null), null);
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
            //return the T type object:         
            return destination;
        }
```

Is there any way to convert this method from c# to java script? thanks.

Comment: `$.extend` would do something similar. It depends if you want to search for nested properties.

Comment: hi, @RoryMcCrossan , would you like to give me any example?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var objA = {a: 1, b: 2}; // your source JS object
var objB = {};           // your destination JS object
for(var key in objA) {
    objB[key] = objA[key];
}
console.log(objA);
console.log(objB);
```

Comment: Hi, @EmanuelSaringan, thanks for your reply. do you know any alternative jquery method? but i want to try understand that objA and objB are containing same property. i won't create new destination object objB.